# Adding element in the list using conj and doseq in clojure

Tags: clojure

In the below code I am trying to add an element in the list using **(conj listvalue countString)**

```
(defn unique-character [parms]
  (let [split (#(str/split % #"") parms)
        countString (count split)
        listvalue #{}]
  (dbg (doseq [countString split]
               (println countString)
               (conj listvalue countString)
               (println listvalue)
         ))listvalue))

(unique-character "Leeeeeerrroyyy")

Output to be - Leroy
```

But I am getting an empty list as an output result

Can someone help me why the character is not added to the list, Maybe this is not good code but I wanted to understand how conj behaves inside doseq

Comment: Clojure uses immutalbe data structures and you can not `conj` onto a list and _modify_ the list. You have to keep hold of the result.

Comment: The manual (https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html) addresses your specific question about "why...not". As for what to do instead, @AlanThompson gave a good reading list. Step 1 is, you do not need to write a whole function and then wonder why it does not work! Clojure is easier than that. Open a REPL and try conj all by itself, then try it in a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly, `conj` will not change the input sequence, instead it will *return* a new version of the input sequence with the element added at the end:

```
(def x [:a :b :c])

(conj x :d)
x
;; => [:a :b :c]

(def y (conj x :d))
y
;; => [:a :b :c :d]
```

This is one of many important reasons why you would want to use Clojure and its standard library over imperative languages and their standard libraries: Having functions return new version of collections instead of modifying them makes the data flow through the program easier to reason about and makes concurrency easier, too.

You also don't need to split the string using `split`, because it can be treated like a sequence directly. It is true that `doseq` will loop over a sequence element-by-element, like for-each-loops in other languages, for the sake of some *side-effect* in every iteration. But `conj` does not have a side effect except for returning a new version of the input sequence.

In this scenario, we would instead use `reduce` that will, just like `doseq`, iterate over a sequence. But it will keep track of a value (`loop-state`) in the code below, that holds the state of the loop and is returned at the end. Here is a rewritten version of the function `unique-characters` of the question asked:

```
(defn unique-characters [parms]
  (reduce (fn [loop-state input-character]
            (conj loop-state input-character)) ;; <-- Return next loop state

          #{} ;; <-- Initial loop state (that is "listvalue")

          parms ;; <-- The input string (sequence of characters)
          ))

(unique-characters "Leeeeeerrroyyy")
;; => #{\e \L \o \r \y}
```

This will return a set of the character of the input sequence. From how the question is worded, this might not be the result that you would like. Here is a modified version that adds each character to the output sequence at most once and makes a string.

```
(defn unique-characters-2 [parms]
  (apply str ;; <-- Build a string from the value returned by reduce below
         (reduce (fn [loop-state input-character]
                   (if (some #(= input-character %) loop-state)
                     loop-state
                     (conj loop-state input-character)))

                 [] ;; <-- Initial loop state

                 parms ;; <-- Input string (sequence of characters)
                 )))

(unique-characters-2 "Leeeeeerrroyyy")
;; => "Leroy"
```

Comment: Any link which says which one to use between reduce and doseq? I always get confused about which function can be used in clojure

Comment: I would try out either one of doseq and reduce on small examples until I understand what they do. They are both based on loop, so you may want to study loop first.

Answer (score 2):

More idiomatic:

```
(defn unique-character [s]
  (clojure.string/join (dedupe s)))
```

`dedupe` deduplicates string characters while keeping appearing order.
However, it returns a list of characters.
`clojure.string/join` joins the list of characters to a string.

```
(unique-character "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy")
;; => "Leroy"
```

But this works too:

```
(defn add-if-new [s s1]
  (if (clojure.string/includes? s s1) s (str s s1)))

(defn unique-character [s]
  (reduce add-if-new (clojure.string/split s #"")))
```

`(str s s1)` is kind of a `conj` on string `s` by element `s1`.

Comment: Thank you :), Yes I knew inbuilt functions but wanted to explore it. So written code elaborately

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to deduplicate in clojure.

the aforementioned `dedupe` is obviously the best, since it is short AND in the standard library.

but there are more:

1. exploring the standard lib you will find handy functions for seq manipulation, like `partition-by` and `map`:

   ```
   (->> "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy"
        (partition-by identity)
        (map first)
        (apply str))

   ;;=> "Leroy"
   ```

   or their `transducers` counterparts variant:

   ```
   (apply str (eduction (partition-by identity) (map first) "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy"))

   ;;=> "Leroy"
   ```
2. you could think of using `iterate`:

   ```
   (->> "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy"
        (iterate #(drop-while #{(first %)} %))
        (take-while seq)
        (map first)
        (apply str))

   ;;=> "Leroy"
   ```
3. `reduce` is always good, especially if you can abstract the logic:

   ```
   (defn vec-conj-unless-last [data x]
     (cond (empty? data) [x]
           (= x (peek data)) data
           :else (conj data x)))

   (apply str (reduce vec-conj-unless-last [] "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy"))

   ;;=> "Leroy"
   ```

   the nice thing about abstracting the logic, is that in can be applied in other places if needed, like you can use this function in loop:

   ```
   (loop [data "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy" res []]
     (if (seq data)
       (recur (rest data) (vec-conj-unless-last res (first data)))
       (apply str res)))

   ;;=> "Leroy"
   ```
4. if you're deduplicating string content, as in your example, you could use the regex for that:

   ```
   (clojure.string/replace "Leeeerrrooyyyyyyy" #"(.)\1*" "$1")

   ;;=> "Leroy"
   ```